# how to get a hidden field value from iframe to parent page in php

Tags: php, facebook, session, codeigniter, iframe

hi 
 i am developing a facebook application in codeigniter which allows user to upload images and videos to my server. i am using iframe to upload images & uploading files using jquery. uploading is working fine. but i need to get the file name in my parent page. . i tried to set session, session value is getting inside iframe page but not getting inside my parent page.how to access that file name? any one please help me...
                             thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display a filename to prnet iframe, without using jQuery

```
 <script>
     parent.document.getElemntByid["elemntID"].innerHTML = '<?php echo $yourfilname;?>'
 </script>
```

Comment: @Elijan Sejic when i add this code i m getting this error Error: Permission denied for <http://myservername> to get property Window.document
Source File:

Comment: @Limi Is your iframe on your domain?? This usually means that iframes are not from same domain

Comment: @Limi subdomain?? As mentioned this is security restriction when trying to set a property from child to a parent iframe on different domains. (to prevent cross Site Scripting). what browser are you using?

Comment: @Elijan Sejic not the sub domain. i am using mozilla firefox version 3.6.16

Comment: @Elijan Sejic since i am developing a facebook application restriction is due to that?

Comment: @Limi I cant tell you unless I see the code. If your parent frame is on yourdomain.com/index.php and iframe is on youdomain.com/myiframe.php then it should work. Otherwise its a problem: See: http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&hs=Y7T&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=%3A+Permission+denied+for+to+get+property+Window.document+&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=
 as well as 
http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=121897834504447&topic=74 .
Try different browsers